# IIS7 default document

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, iis-7

I have manually set the default document inside of IIS 7 on multiple web sites but cannot get them to remain set after a promotion of code. Virtual Directories are fine. I know we can specify the default doc in the web.config but I'd like to simply continue to set it in IIS 7. Anyone else having this issue. I'm sure its a fairly simple answer but I'm fresh off working in IIS6 where you set it once and you're good.

Answer (score 0):

William,

Are you setting this globally or individually through each site?
From the site root level, clicking on default document and then add default document.

It might also be a matter of scheduling time to restart IIS after having made these changes? I am not sure if these changes are written to disk until after IIS is reset.

There is also a way through PowerShell

Add-WebConfiguration //defaultDocument/files "IIS:\sites\WEB1\servertest" -atIndex 0 -Value @{value="servertest.aspx"}

Comment: Thank you Nicholas! I've been setting the document at the root site level but have not tried an IISReset. When I set it at the site root level it prompts to revert to parent. I've not tested reverting because I just built the farm and didn't want to bring anything down until I had a bit of experience with it. I appreciate your help very much.